# Android Live Wallpaper settings button not sending me to settings

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

So I've managed to get the settings button to appear while in the preview for my live wallpaper.  The only issue I'm having is that it's not shooting me to my preference activity.  (I've logged it and I never enter the activity).

I have a feeling I must have made a mistake in the XML somewhere... But I cant seem to spot it.

Here's my wallpaper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
   android:description="@string/wallpaper_description"
   android:settingsActivity="com.company.app.package.LiveWallpaperPrefs">
</wallpaper>
```

Here's the relevant snippet from my manifest.

```
<service
    android:name="com.company.app.package.LiveWallpaperService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="app"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
        android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
</service>

<activity android:name="com.company.app.package.LiveWallpaperPrefs"/>
```

Anybody know why It's not sending me to my LiveWallpaperPrefs when I press settings?  It's actually currently giving me an error "Unfortunately, Live Wallpaper Picker has stopped."

Thanks!

---

Actually figured it out...  I wasn't giving the system permission to enter that settings portion of my app from outside of my app...  Here's what fixed my code.

In the manifest (replacing the old LiveWallpaperPrefs)

```
<activity android:name="com.company.app.package.LiveWallpaperPrefs">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could export the LiveWallpaperPrefs like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.app.package.LiveWallpaperPrefs"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, but I was having a similar problem. None of the suggestions I found online *seemed* to be working. No matter what I did, the settings would not display when you tapped the button.

After wasting about 3 hours, I realized that **it WAS working**, but for some reason I had to completely REMOVE the app from the device and re-install it fresh.

Usually, cleaning the project and re-uploading it to the device actually changes the app. But for some reason *the change would not take effect until the app was removed and re-installed*.

Hope this helps someone in the future!